# How to handle unexpected fatal error with signal?

Tags: python

My goal is to handle unexpected fatal error with signal. However, none of the signal is triggered. For example, `AttributeError`. The example is trivial. What I want is to execute a function i.e. `camera.stop()` before closing the app regardless of how bad it is. Otherwise, I will need to reboot to use the camera.

```
def signal_handler():
    print("do something")

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, signal_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("a{}".fomrat())
```

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_not_rethrown.py", line 12, in <module>
    print("a{}".fomrat())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fomrat'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be catching exceptions for that?

Comment: Python exceptions do not generate signals

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I don't want to handle every exception. The current solution is to mimic `go defer` statement which is `import atexit` and `atexit.register(command_that_will_execute_at_exit)`.